# issues with creating permissions in Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto, boto3, mechanicalturk

In order to send messages via mTurk to SQS the corresponding permission to `SendMessage` should be given. In documentation they say that the Principal should be `mturk-requester.amazonaws.com`. So the policy that works looks like:

```
"Principal": {
  "Service": "mturk-requester.amazonaws.com"
 },
```

This can be done via Boto3.SQS.addPermission. Like that:

```
response = client.add_permission(
   QueueUrl='string',
   Label='string',
    AWSAccountIds=[
       'string',
   ],
  Actions=[
      'string',
  ]
 )
```

but I fail to understand how I can add the correct Principal to `AWSAccountIds` field. All my attempts to use `mturk-requester.amazonaws.com` there failed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're battling some erroneous MTurk documentation (i.e. [the example policy document is invalid](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_NotificationReceptorAPI_SQSTransportArticle.html#ApiReference_NotificationReceptorAPI_SQSTransportArticle-policy-document)), as well as some under-documented Boto3 behavior (i.e. you can't pass a complex structure to `SQS.add_permission`).

I was able to programmatically add the policy by using `set_queue_attributes` instead of `add_permission`.

```python
import re
import json

q = client.create_queue(QueueName='queue1001')

q_parts = re.search('(\d+)/(.+)$', q['QueueUrl'])
aws_id = q_parts.group(1)
q_name = q_parts.group(2)

policy = {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "mturk-requester.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:{}:{}".format(aws_id, q_name),
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:SecureTransport": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

client.set_queue_attributes(QueueUrl=q['QueueUrl'], Attributes={'Policy': json.dumps(policy)})
```

The main difference being the use of

```js
"Condition": {
  "Bool": {
    "aws:SecureTransport": "true"
  }
}
```

instead of

```js
"aws:SecureTransport":"true"
```

which doesn't parse in the AWS Policy Validator.

Comment: Worth noting that this works for integrating with a lot of other services, not just mturk.  I used it with SNS.